# need help creating an if statment that will work for my purpose in .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I have edited my .bashrc to look like this with some help from others on this forum ... Thanks guys for the help on the weather segment of this script...[image]

An issue I have ran into is the code for the external ip address. If for some reason the site I use to check the external IP doesn't respond .. it locks up my bash at that point until it gets the information.

What I would like to do is change it so that I can have it so if it doesn't respond in a second or 500ms .. then to just move on so it doesn't hang. I hope that makes sense .. here is the code I'm using for it.

```
localnet()
{
declare -a INETARRAY
INETARRAY=( `/sbin/ifconfig | awk /'inet addr/ {print $2}' && /sbin/ifconfig | awk /'Bcast/ {print $3}'`)
echo -ne ${INETARRAY[@]} "ExtIP:" ; myip
}
myip ()
{
lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=ignore -nolist http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/ | grep "Current IP Address" | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d" " -f2
}
```

Basically I need an if statement that would do something like this:

if the site doesn't give whats expected withing a configurable amount of time load "line 1" else load "line 2"

Line 1 would contain the code without the external IP request 
Line 2 would contain the code with the external IP request.

Now .. I'm not actually sure what is causing the hang .. I don't know if the site is not responding .. or if it is busy and taking longer to respond or if its getting information but not whats expected ... it happens sporadically and if it hangs on me I can close the shell and open it and usually it will get the information .. I thought about ping but ... again .. not sure if the site would still respond to the ping but not produce what the script is looking for and still hang.

I just don't know how to set up the statement correctly to make this happen or something similar

Thanks in advanced.

I tried the line suggested by glenn jackman

```
curl --silent --output - --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 3 http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/ | grep "Current IP Address" | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"" -f2
```

It did get the IP address but the resulted in this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

I will have to probably adjust the second cut command .. lol .. guess I need to learn cut :D

If i use

```
curl --silent --output - --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 3 http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/ | grep "Current IP Address"
```

I get the output of:

```
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

If I switch back to the lynx line instead of curl and use the `-read_timeout=1 -connect-timeout=1` this does keep the shell from hanging if it has connections issues but .. it produces errors which was why I was hoping to make some sort of if statement

```
Network: addr:192.168.1.20 addr:127.0.0.1 Bcast:192.168.1.255 ExtIP:
Looking up checkip.dyndns.org:8245
Making HTTP connection to checkip.dyndns.org:8245
Alert!: Connection failed (too many retries).
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/
```

Comment: I use this: `curl --silent --output - --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 3 $URL`

Comment: Also, be prepared to switch to a different source for this information: third party sites come and go. You can host your own: with PHP, it's a one-liner.

Comment: yeah .. this is dyndns .. they have been around forever and probably will stay around for years to come but .. how can I set it up with php .. if you can put it in an answer maybe I can try that instead .. im sure it would probably be must faster and more stable if I could run it on my system .. but wouldn't it just give me my local IP not the external one?

Comment: not be able to add to the problem solving but i would be interested in the complete script :) yould be nice if you could up it on http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: the curl line seems to work but now I have an issue with the cut line .. its showing </body></html> after the IP address now

Comment: What is the html output of the curl command? Add that to your question so it can be formatted properly.

Comment: If you want to stick with lynx, it has both a `-read_timeout` and `-connect_timeout` - try setting those

Comment: so it would be something like `lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=ignore -nolist  -read_timeout -connect_timeout http://website` or is it `read_timeout=500` or something like that

Comment: It would be something like `-read_timeout=1` for 1 second - read the man page

Comment: Couldn't the myip section be this:  `curl --silent --output - --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 3 icanhazip.com` ?

Comment: I get this : `curl: (7) Failed to connect to checkip.dyndns.org port 8245: Connection refused`  If I remove the port , it works, fairly fast.  Can't it be your network speed ?

Comment: no like i say its sporadic most of the times it connects only some times it hangs .. but .. seems like terrance has helped me out .. that address just posts the ip address and doesn't need to be 'grepped' or  cut . I have tried both with the port and without .. figured with would be better because most traffic would be using port 80

Comment: @JohnOrion What you might want to do is write the corrections in as your own answer and select it as the right answer.  You get no points for selecting your own answer, but it will help others here as well and they can upvote the answer.  Post the link in your answer to the .bashrc.  I really like the looks of it as well.

Comment: wow, tl;dr. Just a Note: you could just paste the actual characters of a terminal window, from **copy & paste** and use the "code" formatting, instead of an *image* (unless the colour's vital)

Comment: lol to each his own... I have  seen people put links for images and their post gets edited and the pictures are added in line .. sorry if its too long for you .. it seems others preferred that the post was in depth and all relevant information was given. It should be quite obvious that I am aware of the `code formatting` by the  post.

Comment: I ended up reading it ;-) Is there a link to the weather script you're using? Or is it all in the .bashrc in the answer? May be useful for a conky rc...  And I meant your image was just a text terminal, pasting the text itself would be as good as an image (& better for website storage, not that it's much of a concern apparently)

Comment: I see sorry I misinterpretation it  as for the code its in the answer I posted... there is a link to the bashrc file in there that shows the whole code... the reason I linked the image instead of just the text  was to show how it was laid out where  the text wouldn't really show how it "looked"

Comment: The function is called weather and is on lines 69-74

Comment: Thanks ... (I'll del this comment soon - wouldn't let me post without typing a little more than just "thanks")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seem to be a working solution is using the curl command suggested by glenn jackman and the address suggested by Terrance. I haven't run into the hang yet so I don't know if it will through any errors but it seems to work well.. the new line is now

```
curl --silent --output - --connect-timeout 1 --max-time 2 http://icanhazip.com/
```

which seems to be working .. I have launched the terminal 10 times without a hang or an error. I think you guys did it again... Man I wish where was something like this forum for Windows... lol you go on their forums and ask a question .. you get a non related  'form letter response' and then nothing.

You guys are great .. I think this has now got the terminal shell just the way I want it and no hanging .. lol I disabled the external IP thing for a while because of the annoyance but now I can have it back again :D

If anyone decides to use the [.bashrc I linked](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16269979/)  lol its slightly plagiarized but I don't remember the original person I got it from when the script first started out but I have been playing with it ever since.. it was like in 2010 or something.

The file also includes a link to .bashrcc that you can create where you can add  commands and aliases without having to put them in the main file. This was done because I sync my bashrc across several computers and there are times where I want a special alias for one computer but I don't it available on all the PC's that are synced to the file. The .bashrcc will allow me to add it for one user only. Also remember that you will have to change the `weather` function with your zip code or you will be viewing my area's temps :D